# using photoshop, how can i put a logo on a object like a can (image attached)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

I have a logo and i want to place it on a graphic but on certain graphics the logo is bigger than the "flat" surface so i want to "bend" the logo appropriately to make it look real.

For example, on this image below:

[image]

the 7-up logo bends around the can.  When i put a logo on this type of 3 dimensional surface, it looks wrong so i assume there is some technique to make the logo match to the object.

Comment: Back in the day, they would actually hand-paint a can and then photograph it. I had to do this for some prototypes for a toy company once.

Comment: Back in the day, they hand-set lead type, too. The skills we've lost, sigh...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid moving out of Photoshop and into a 3D rendering application, then you should look into using the **Warp Transform** tool (found under Edit > Transform > Warp).

Here is a link to a step-by-step tutorial that demonstrates how to use the Warp tool to do something similar to what you describe:  <s>http://csscreme.com/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/warp_tool_effect_photoshop_tutorial</s>

**EDIT:**

The Warp transform was added in Photoshop CS2. If you are using an older version, you are not totally out of luck. While it is a bit harder to get the look right, you can experiment with using the **Shear tool** to curve your logo around the can. This tutorial demonstrates some of the features and operations of the shear tool:  <s>http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/warping-more-than-just-text.7380.html</s>

**EDIT 2016:**

Both tutorial links seem to be broken. An alternative to the Warp Transform tutorial can be found here: http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/making-sense-of-the-warp-tool-its-all-about-the-lines--psd-3896

An archived version of the Shear tool tutoral may be accessed via the Wayback Machine, here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150919030019/http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/warping-more-than-just-text.7380.html

Comment: thats exactly what i want except it doesn't seem to be supported in photoshop 7 :(

Comment: @ooo I updated my answer with something that might help you.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible method is using illustrator. You can warp every custom shape using object > envelope distort > choose something here.

If you make a custom shape in your form then apply this using object > envelope distort > Make with top object. The form will then be shaped according to the top mesh or path. You can alter it afterwards. This is vector though, so no pixel images.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop isn't a 3-D rendering application, though it does have some effects and tools for emulating it.

I'd consider looking into Google SketchUp. You could render a 3-d Can shape, apply your graphic to it, render it, then export that for use back in PhotoShop.

Comment: i removed the term 3d from the question as i don't really need a 3d rendering application.  i just am trying to figure out the technique in photoshop to wrap a logo around an image. (see attached image)

Comment: What you are asking for is exactly that: how to take a 2D image and make it appear wrapped around a 3D object. The best way to handle that is via a program designed for 3D rendering.

Comment: i included an example so I am not sure how much more clear i can be.  Lets say the can above didn't have the 7up logo on it and i had a separate 7up logo.  how can i put the 7 up logo on the can and have it look aligned properly

Comment: And I'm not sure how much more clear I can be. What you are asking for is EXACTLY what SketchUp can do. It's a feature of the software. I'm a fan of using the right tool for the job, and given that SketchUp is a free tool, I strongly suggest giving it a shot. This is just not something PhotoShop, by itself, is designed to handle.

Comment: Sean's answer above is exactly what i want but it turns out its not supported in photoshop 7